# Purpose of allowing unnecessary semicolons in class definition

Tags: c++, syntax

Consider following program:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Test
{
    int a;
    Test(int s) : a(s)
    { };        // Observe this semicolon
    int geta()
    {
        return a;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Test t(3);
    std::cout<<t.geta()<<'\n';
}
```

The program compiles fine even when I use `-pedantic-errors` option in both gcc & clang. (See live demo [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/eIJfrZvZGZsKFnuz) & [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xGcauTdm3pCSPr0n).) I also don't get any error from compiler if I put semicolon at the end of geta() member function like following:

```
int geta()
{
   return a;
}; // This also compiles fine without any error or warnings in both g++ & clang
```

So, what is the purpose of allowing this unnecessary semicolon? Is there any use of this? Is it allowed explicitly by language standard?

Comment: Isn't that just like an empty command, a "do-nothing" command ?

Comment: @Coffee Commands are not allowed at class scope. He is talking about class scope, not function scope.

Comment: A single semicolon is classified as a declaration statement, not a "do-something" statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Semicolon (;) stands for empty declaration in c++. You can see [Declarations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations)

C++ class allows following things inside the braces:

list of access specifiers

member object

member function declarations and definitions

Reference:[Class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class)

Thus going by above rule, empty declarations are allowed in c++. Which is why you have semicolon.